# Reemplazar tabulaciones por comas en un archivo .csv

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv

Tengo un archivo .csv que representa una tabla con 12931 entradas. Por ejemplo:

```
ID  A   B   C
1   9   hola    despues de hola va una coma 383
2   8   esto es sin comas   383
3   2   hola    los tabs en este campo son una coma estoy en B  383
```

Bueno se puede deducir que ID,A y C son numéricos y B es string. El problema que tengo es que quiero encontrar una forma lo más automática posible de reemplazar los tabs que aparecen en B por una coma en el bloc de notas o en otro editor. Hay que tener en cuenta que como es un poco variable lo estaba haciendo a mano. Pero son 12931 filas. La tabla final en el .csv sería

```
ID  A   B   C
1   9   hola,despues de hola va una coma    383
2   8   esto es sin comas   383
3   2   hola,los tabs en este campo son una coma,estoy en B     383
```

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo automático? En excel no puedo porque hay símbolos especiales que no soporta.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje quieres hacerlo? Debes ponerlo en las etiquetas de tu pregunta, o al menos mencionarlo.

Comment: En cualquier lenguaje. Preferentemente en Vb .net . La idea es exportar ese .csv en el SQL Server Management Studio.. O al menos encomillar las strings de B después de reemplazar TODOS los tabs del archivo por una coma

Comment: @Isalvatore no sé si tal vez esto te pueda funcionar en algo: http://code2care.org/pages/replace-tabs-by-spaces-or-comma-notepad-plus-plus/

Comment: Si utilizas la coma como separador tal vez no te quede como quieres. En las columnas de texto tienes el carácter coma incluido dentro de los textos.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede servir a continuacion te indicare como hacerlo en SQL y Java

SQL :

```
    select replace(Columna_B, char(9), ' , ')
```

Java :

```
    columnaB = columnaB.replace("\t"," ,");
```

Saludos.

Comment: "Preferiblemente en Vb.Net", pone en un comentario el OP.